# Automatic suspend option is not available in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop

Tags: 20.04, suspend, remote-desktop

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.2 LTS and I would like to enable the Automatic Suspend option. I have followed the [instruction](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-autosuspend.html.en) from the official site but the option is not available. Only a "Blank screen" option is available.

Is the documentation wrong or what could be the reason for this?

I am using the PC as a media server without a monitor attached. I am connected via xrdp. Could this be the reason?
Manual suspend works.

Specs:

- Asrock h470m-hdv Mainboard
- BeQuiet System Power 300W PSU
- Intel i3 10100 CPU

Comment: isn't your reference related to ubuntu 21.04?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your computer without logging into it locally so probably you need to configure it via service `systemd-logind` - [Login manager](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-logind.service.8.html).

You can use [Login manager configuration files](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/logind.conf.5.html) - `logind.conf`, `logind.conf.d`. Take a look at the following options:

- `IdleAction`
- `IdleActionSec`
- `HandlePowerKey`, `HandleSuspendKey`, `HandleHibernateKey`, `HandleLidSwitch`, `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower`, `HandleLidSwitchDocked`
- and other appropriate options.